# Bound the button to top right corner of the view iOS swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, layout

I have a view in which i have multiple labels [image]and a button i want the button to be bound to the top right corner

when i apply the add Missing constraints layout the button gets separate position for different devices Please help me to resolve this

Comment: add Missing constraints is a bad option to go with ... just set constraints one by one as per your need

Comment: **NEVER** use "add missing constraints" - always add the constraints yourself.

Comment: for top right corner you need to set constraints like : Trailing : 0 , Top :0 Fix Height and Fix Width

Comment: i have the same problem with the label how to fit it to bottom and centrally

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NEVER use `add missing constraints`. This is a bad way of constructing your layout.

The easiest way to get your desired look is to decide on the size you want your button to be (eg. 30x30)

Then you add the following constraints to your button:

This sets the button's width & Height:

[image]

Then pin it to the right top corner:

[image]

Comment: i have a label inside which there is string names and integer values i want to Bold the integer values with out effecting the string can u please resolve this

Answer (score 7):

[image]    //Just in case if anybody needs it with code:

```
//I have added 4 buttons to a custom view's each corner:

var customView = UIView()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        customView.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
        customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red     //give color to the view
        customView.center = self.view.center

        let crossButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: -10, y: -10, width: 30, height: 30))
        crossButton.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        crossButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        crossButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "cross.png"), for: .normal)
        crossButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(crossButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        crossButton.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleBottomMargin]


        let flipButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: customView.frame.width-15, y: -10, width: 30, height: 30))
        flipButton.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        flipButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        flipButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "done.png"), for: .normal)
        flipButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(crossButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        flipButton.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleBottomMargin]

        let scaleButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: -10, y: customView.frame.height-20, width: 30, height: 30))
        scaleButton.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        scaleButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        scaleButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "done.png"), for: .normal)
        scaleButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(crossButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        scaleButton.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleBottomMargin]

        let editButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: customView.frame.width-20, y: customView.frame.height-20, width: 30, height: 30))
        editButton.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        editButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        editButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "done.png"), for: .normal)
        editButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(crossButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        editButton.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleBottomMargin]

        customView.addSubview(crossButton)
        customView.addSubview(flipButton)
        customView.addSubview(scaleButton)
        customView.addSubview(editButton)

        self.view.addSubview(customView)

    }

    func crossButtonTapped(_ sender:UIButton) {

        print("Cross Button was tapped")
    }
```